# Why does the difference in calculation confidence interval occur?

Tags: r, statistics

I am about to calculate the confidence interval(CI) for the proportion.
The data is like this:

```
End Count
death 57
pat 319
```

where pat means the total number of sample.

I used following formula:

```
#lower CI
57/319 - 1.96*sqrt(57/319*(1-57/319)/319)
#upper CI
57/319 + 1.96*sqrt(57/319*(1-57/319)/319)
```

Formulas above gave the result of [0.1366, 0.2207].

However, when I used prop.test(),

```
prop.test(57, 319, correct = FALSE)
```

The result was [0.1405442, 0.2244692].

Could you please explain how this happen?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confidence intervals are an approximation assuming a normal distribution. For count data and especially for proportions, this assumption can be very inaccurate, especially if the proportion is not approximately .5 or the sample size is small. The 'prop.test()' function estimates an asymmetric interval (notice that 57/319 does not lie in the middle of the interval). The method used is documented in the article cited on the manual page (`?prop.test`). The manual page also notes that the estimate used in `binom.test` can be more accurate:

binom.test(57, 319)

```
Exact binomial test

data:  57 and 319
number of successes = 57, number of trials = 319, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1382331 0.2252183
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.1786834
```

The difference between all three is small, but `binom.test()` should be your choice if it makes a difference in whether or not to reject the null hypothesis.